# How to show image view in table view from json

Tags: swift, api, web-services, uitableview, uiimageview

To parse json i have following function

```
 func single_news(userid: Int) {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: news_url)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        //Pass your parameter here
        let postString = "userid=\(userid)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("error=(error)")
                return
            }


            let json: Any?

            do
            {

                json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print("abcnews")
                //here is your JSON
                print(json)
                let jsonValue : NSDictionary = json as! NSDictionary
                self.results = jsonValue.object(forKey: "data") as! [[String:String]]
                self.DiscoveryNewsTableView.delegate = self
                self.DiscoveryNewsTableView.dataSource = self
                self.DiscoveryNewsTableView.reloadData()

//                let _ = getData.shared.getDataForTableView(dict: json)
            }
            catch
            {
                return
            }

            guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else
            {
                return
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

To get data the class is created

```
class getData: NSObject {

    var descriptionn : String = ""
    var image : String = ""

//    static let shared = getData()

    func getDataForTableView(results: [[String:String]], index : Int){

        var productArray = [String:String]()
        productArray = results[index]

        descriptionn = productArray["description"]!
        image = productArray["images"]!
    }
}
```

To display data in table view

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "discoveryNewscell") as! DiscoveryNewsTableViewCell

//        if results.count > 0{
            classObject.getDataForTableView(results: results, index: indexPath.row)
            cell.sneakerImageView.image=filteredsneakernews[indexPath.row].image
                   print("abc image"+classObject.image)
        cell.newsTitle.text = classObject.descriptionn
//        }
        return cell
    }
```

How to display the image .Image(classObject.image) in string format how to display image view on table view ?you can download the code from this link .https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bVQsuSQINSa6YRwZe2QwEjPpU_m7S3b8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You're wanting to display an image but you only have the URL to that image and not the image itself so you'll need to download it, then display it. I have a class I use a lot that allows you to simply call one line to download AND cache the image so you'll be able to do something like this:

```
classObject.getDataForTableView(results: results, index: indexPath.row)
let image_url = filteredsneakernews[indexPath.row].image
cell.sneakerImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: image_url!)
```

To do this, you'll have to copy the class below and inside your cell class, you’ll want to change the imageView type from a standard UIImageView to a CustomImageView for example:

```
let imageView: CustomImageView!
```

//

```
import UIKit

let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

class CustomImageView: UIImageView {

    var imageUrlString: String?

    func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: String) {

        imageUrlString = urlString

        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }

        self.image = nil

        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil { return }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                    if self.imageUrlString == urlString {
                        if self.imageUrlString != "" {
                            self.image = downloadedImage
                        } else {
                            self.image = nil
                        }
                    }

                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                }
            }

        }).resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: cell.sneakerImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: image_url!)/////This line is giving syntax error ////
 Error: Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString'

Comment: @ajadka Edited my answer

Comment: Second error.... let imageView: CustomImageView!
/////Global 'let' declaration requires an initializer expression

Comment: @ajadka That was just an example. You’ll need to do the same thing but with your sneakersImageView. Don’t actually add in the “let imageView: CustomImageView!”

Comment: I put this statement.... @IBOutlet weak var sneakerImageView: CustomImageView!.....in DiscoveryNewsTableViewCell this statement......cell.sneakerImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: image_url!)
        .....  is giving me error ///... Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'UIImage'